# Foreach array within an object

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I've got a PHP object. One of the values within the object is in array. I'm trying to get a foreach to just read the array within the object but it doesn't seem to be working.

**PHP:**

```
foreach ($object->ArrayName as $value) {

    echo $value;

}
```

is there any way of doing this?

Comment: `foreach($obj->arrayName as $array) { foreach($array as $item) { echo $item; }}` ?

Comment: first var_dump($object) and put your output

Comment: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/6/7/6

Comment: What does `it doesn't seem to be working` exactly mean? You get no output? You get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, if you have an object but you don't know which property is an array, you need to catch them all and verify if they are an array:

```
// get each value of the object and call it as property
foreach(get_object_vars($object) as $property) {

    // if this property is an array...
    if (is_array($property) {

        // ... access to every value of that array
        foreach($property as $value) {

            // $property is your array and $value is every value
            // here you can execute what you need

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
 is_array($obj) 
 to validate whether it's an array or not.

Answer (score 0):

you said your php object contains arrays, hence you need to use 2 foreach loops like this.

```
<?php
    foreach($object->ArrayName as $value) {
        foreach($value as $item) {
            echo $item;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Taken straight from my [**comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177913/foreach-array-within-an-object#comment39202840_25177913)...

Comment: Its known to any basic PHP programmer. No need to take it from you:)

Answer (score -1):

if the loop is withing the object wich mean inside the class use `$this` instead :

```
foreach ($this->ArrayName as $value) {

    echo $value;

}
```